# System wide adapter in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying configure a "system wide" custom `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter` for the `java.util.Locale` type in Jersey.  It's easy enough to use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on classes I control but that's not always the case (3rd party code that I can't annotate).

It seems like it would be a pretty common problem but I can't find any good examples or doco on how to handle it.

So, is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: could you not just use a delegate?

Answer (score 1):

I can see three possible options:

1. Register the converter with the marshaller with [setAdapter()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#setAdapter(java.lang.Class,%20A)). You can have a static builder function which adds all your 'system level' type adapters to all marshallers which you use in your application. It all depends on your definition of 'system level'
2. Use a delegate
3. Do some fancy [bytecode trickery](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-annotations.html) to add the annotations to existing class files.

My advice would be to use approach 1, which is simple and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I managed to get it going using a package level `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.

I had to a look at the `setAdapter()` method.  The javadoc seems to suggest that it still requires the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`...?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to annotate classes you can't modify, you could always use the [externalized metadata feature](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML) of [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).

The metadata file would look something like:

```
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="java.util.Locale">
            <xml-java-type-adapter value="some.package.YourAdapter"/>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

To you EclipseLink MOXy you need to add a jaxb.properties file in with your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: This does not work as of Moxy 2.6: a package-name is required. And if added, you get "The java-type with package [java.util] is not allowed in the bindings file keyed on package"

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at [JAXBIntroductions](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JAXBIntroductions) project which is intended for similar purpose. The annotation configuration is kept in a file, without requiring modification to source code. It does work nicely with Jersey, by implementing a JAX-RS provider. You can check out my blog [entry](http://aruld.info/hate-jaxb-annotations-moxy-and-jaxbintroductions-comes-to-the-rescue/) which explains this in detail with an example. Here is a simple JAXBContextResolver provide for JAXBIntroductions that can be used in your Jersey application.

```
import com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext;
import org.jboss.jaxb.intros.IntroductionsAnnotationReader;
import org.jboss.jaxb.intros.IntroductionsConfigParser;
import org.jboss.jaxb.intros.configmodel.JaxbIntros;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import java.util.*;

@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolverForJAXBIntroductions implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private final JAXBContext context;
    private final Set<Class> types;
    private final Class[] cTypes = {Customer.class};

    public JAXBContextResolverForJAXBIntroductions() throws Exception {
        this.types = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(cTypes));
        JaxbIntros config = IntroductionsConfigParser.parseConfig(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/intro-config.xml"));
        IntroductionsAnnotationReader reader = new IntroductionsAnnotationReader(config);
        Map<String, Object> jaxbConfig = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        jaxbConfig.put(JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER, reader);
        this.context = JAXBContext.newInstance(cTypes, jaxbConfig);
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return (types.contains(objectType)) ? context : null;
    }
}
```